# How to find parent form from element?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find parent form from element using code below:

```
<form id="f1" action="action1.html">
form1 <button id="btn1" onclick="testaction(this); return false;" >test form 1</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript" >
function testaction(element) {
    var e = $(element.id);
    var form = e.parent('form');

    alert(form.id); // undefined!!
    alert(form.action); // undefined!!
    alert(document.forms[0].action); //http://localhost/action1.html
}
</script>
```

It should be something really simple.... Thanks in advance

Comment: `.parent` only gives the immediate ancestor.

Comment: You should just `$(element)` instead of `$(element.id)`.

Comment: how about `btn1.form`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Throw the inline event handler aboard and stay unobtrusive here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn1').bind('click', function(){
      var form = $(this).closest('form')[0];

      alert(form.id); // defined
      alert(form.action); // defined
   });
});
```

Ref.: [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: `closest("form")[0]` was the correct solution, returning a proper element. `parent('form').get(0)` returned `undefined`!

Answer (score 48):

http://api.jquery.com/closest/ will do it. Used like this

```
$('#elem').closest('form');
```

Comment: Best solution, unlike parents() stops once it finds a match

Comment: how it best of `btn1.form`?

Answer (score 16):

The problem you're having is that `form` is a jQuery object, not a DOM object.  If you want it to be the form object, you would do `e.parent('form').get(0)`.

Furthermore, you're treating element incorrectly - jQuery takes id selectors in the form `#id` but you've passed it `id`.

Here's a working version:

```
function testaction(element) {
  var e = $(element);//element not element.id
  var form = e.parent('form').get(0);//.get(0) added

  alert(form.id); // undefined!!
  alert(form.action); // undefined!!
  alert(document.forms[0].action); //http://localhost/action1.html
}
```

See this for it in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/BTmwq/

**EDIT**: spelling, clarity

Comment: Variable `form`would be `undefined` here. The solution by @jAndy worked.

Comment: This is absolutely WRONG code! The `.parent()` only travels a single level up the DOM tree, so if the form contains some mid-level parent like as when the element is inside a `div` (eg: `form > div > element` ), this function will return that `div` not the form!!!

Comment: @S.Serpooshan - In the example given in the question, the form is the direct parent.  If you want the form and it might be higher in the DOM tree, you would use `closest('form')`

Comment: @Ryley yes i see, but this is very common to have several containers around html elements. do you think your solution is reliable?? usually such kind of solutions will break the code very soon when you continue to add more features to your code later without knowing where is the problem..

Answer (score 10):

Button element has form property http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_pushbutton.asp

```
buttonElement.form
```

Comment: the `.form` property of input elements is supported by IE 4.0+ !

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".whatever").parents("form");
```

Comment: closest() is a much better solution as it stops once a match is found

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="f1" action="action1.html">
form1 <button id="btn1" onclick="get_attr(this); return false;" >test form 1</button>
</form>

<form id="f2" action="action2.html">
form2 <button type="submit" >test form 2</button>
</form>

<script>

$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    var form = $(this).parent("form").get(0);
    alert("ID: " + form.id);
    alert("Action: " + form.action);
    e.preventDefault();
});
function get_attr(element) {
    var form = $(element).parent("form").get(0);
    alert("ID: " + form.id);
    alert("Action: " + form.action);
}

</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2d9tjLym/)